# Struct init: Braces around scalar initializer for type char**

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I have this struct:

```
struct NetDescriptor {
    unsigned int inputNeuronCount = 1;
    char **inputNeuronType = nullptr;
    unsigned int hiddenNeuronCount = 0;
    unsigned int *hiddenNeurons = nullptr;
    unsigned int outputNeuronCount = 1;
    char **outputNeuronType = nullptr;
};
```

And want to init it in a method of a other class with this code:

```
NetDescriptor nnDescriptor = {
    3,
    {"EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n"},
    3,
    {4,4,3},
    3,
    {"EAT\n","MOVEL\n","MOVER\n"}
};
```

But it only gives me this error:

> line 3: error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'char**'

I tried:

```
{{"EAT\n"},{"FOODL\n"},{"FOODR\n"}},
```

But it doesnt change anything, i also tried it with std::string same result.

Comment: Most of the time if you want a `char **` you should use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead

Comment: Well, yes. You declared `inputNeuronType` as a pointer. A pointer is a single value; you can't initialize it with a list of expressions.

Comment: @melpomene So what do you recommend? I want to define this structure static in code and not something like vec.push_back("EAT");

Comment: What is `inputNeuronType` supposed to do? Does it really need to be a pointer (to another pointer)?

Comment: @melpomene No i just want a Structure which contains a array of strings either std::string or char* and i want to init it with STRUCT = {
{"1","2","3"}}; or something like this.

Comment: @skilled-solutions `std::vector<std::string>` works just fine for that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83149a163218a0cf

Comment: Have you succeeded in initializing a `char**` like that _outside_ of a struct?

Comment: Yeah, this question has nothing to do with structs per se, which is why I removed the `struct` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i just want a Structure which contains a array of strings either
>   std::string or char* and i want to init it with STRUCT = {
>   {"1","2","3"}}; or something like this.

Like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct NetDescriptor
{
    char const *inputNeuronType[3];
};

struct NetDescriptorStr
{
    std::string inputNeuronType[3];
};

struct NetDescriptorDynamic
{
    std::vector<std::string> inputNeuronType;
};

int main()
{
    NetDescriptor nnDescriptor = { { "EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n" } };
    std::cout << nnDescriptor.inputNeuronType[1] << std::endl;

    NetDescriptorStr nnDescriptorStr = { { "EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n" } };
    std::cout << nnDescriptorStr.inputNeuronType[1] << std::endl;

    NetDescriptorDynamic nnDescriptorDynamic = { { "EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n","EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n" } };
    std::cout << nnDescriptorDynamic.inputNeuronType[4] << std::endl;

    NetDescriptorDynamic nnDescriptorDynamic2;
    nnDescriptorDynamic2.inputNeuronType.assign({ "EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n","EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n" });
    std::cout << nnDescriptorDynamic2.inputNeuronType[4] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: This is basically what i mean, but i want it too be dynamic that i only need to add "XYZ\n" to the struct init and not to set anything from 3 to 4. So i thought the pointers would be the solution?

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much i didint know this was possible! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with structs per se.

```
char **inputNeuronType = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

has the same problem.

A pointer is a single value. You can't use a list of expressions to initialize it; you can only point it at some already existing array.

However, if all you really need is the initialization syntax, then a `std::vector<std::string>` would work just fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct NetDescriptor {
    unsigned int inputNeuronCount = 1;
    std::vector<std::string> inputNeuronType;
    unsigned int hiddenNeuronCount = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned int> hiddenNeurons;
    unsigned int outputNeuronCount = 1;
    std::vector<std::string> outputNeuronType;
};

NetDescriptor nnDescriptor = {
    3,
    {"EAT\n","FOODL\n","FOODR\n"},
    3,
    {4,4,3},
    3,
    {"EAT\n","MOVEL\n","MOVER\n"}
};
```

This code Just Works™.

Comment: For you too: Thank you very much! Excactly what i mean, thought vectors can only use push_back for this...

Comment: @skilled-solutions you could use `assign` to maintain format, see my edit